# WordPress Multisite: Automatically run importer upon creating new site

Tags: multisite, import

Is it possible to automatically run the WP Importer when creating a new site in WordPress Multisite?

I think this would need to be a function that runs when **wpmu_new_blog** is called but can't find anything that's helped.

Comment: What do you mean: open the Import page or run an automated import function? If the later, where would the import file come from?

Comment: I believe he means runs during install, this is a question I would love to figure out if I had the time, I would start with the WordPress Importer plugin which can be found here (mirror) , https://github.com/crowdfavorite/mirror-wp-wordpress-importer/blob/master/wordpress-importer.php

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for a multisite (the same and NOT a different wordpress installation), would any of these plugins give a solution to your question?

[New Blog Defaults](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpmu-new-blog-defaults/)

It is a mu-plugin and has been around for some time (I have tried it myself and works just fine). Under *"Bonus Settings"* you are provided with options to customize the first post, the sample page, the first comments, the links, etc. All the settings filled under the plugin's options will be applied to **all new blogs/sites** created **after** the plugin is installed.

[Default Blog](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/default-blog-options/)

This one uses a different approach. **You have to create a *"default"*, *"sample"* blog/site first**. Please have a look at the screenshots. It looks pretty easy to follow. Never tried it though.

Comment: The Default Blog plugin did the job nicely. Don't use the WP.org version (buggy / security vulnerability), get the Github version which is more up to date (though in Alpha).

Comment: @James Glad I could help. Just wondering though. Why don't you accept the answer...